# GCM regID in MySQL: varchar(4096) or text

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I'm worry about when multicast message on GCM returns that a new token should be updated.

I'm planing create and index of reg_id but the only way seems use varchar(4096) that looks like large.

I prefer varchar because is table inline, but it is a reasonable size for a varchar?

It is a good aproach?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine. You should read through the [**thread**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/q2PzJTP71TY/DNX4lvDu5X4J). It explains that 255 is good enough to record reg_id.

Comment: Somebody said it, but nobody explains it.